# Visit all nodes exactly once in a directed graph

Tags: c++, path, directed-graph

I have a directed graph and I want to find a path that visits every node exactly one time. I want to do this with a good complexity. Is this possible? And if yes, how?

Comment: to answer your question: yes it is possible. And now what have you tried so far?

Comment: I run a bfs and I keep a bitmask that says which nodes I have visited.

Comment: Can you explain how can we do this?

Comment: @codePG Can you write your solution?

Comment: Sorry, stackoverflow.com is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to say that I want him to explain his solution.

Answer (score 10):

You are searching for a [**Hamiltonian path**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path), which is a simple open path that contains each node exactly once.

Finding a Hamiltonian path in a given graph is [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness). In fact, determining whether a given (directed or undirected) graph contains a Hamiltonian path is already NP-complete (proven via reduction from e.g. the [vertex cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover)).

If you still want to code it, here is [an implementation on github](https://github.com/obradovic/HamiltonianPath). If you want a fast solution, maybe a heuristic is sufficient (for instance [inspired by DNA molecules](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Masami_Hagiya/publication/2372342_A_Heuristic_Approach_for_Hamiltonian_Path_Problem_with_Molecules/links/55b600ad08aec0e5f436d0db.pdf), or a solution that works fast on a subset of graphs. For instance, if you have a DAG, you can do a topological sort and then check if successive vertices are connected. If so, the topological sort gives a Hamiltonian path.